# Output for get_slice incorrect regardless of elif statement

Tags: python-3.5

I created a function that gets a designated slice from a list.

```
def get_slice(my_list, start, stop):
    new_list = []
    length = 0
    for x in my_list:
        length = length + 1
    if stop > length:
        stop = length
        start = start - 1
        for x in range(start, stop):
            x = my_list[x]
            new_list.append(x)
    elif start > length or start < 1:
        return new_list
    elif start > stop:
        return new_list
    else:
        start = start - 1
        for x in range(start, stop):
            x = my_list[x]
            new_list.append(x)
    print(new_list)
```

Everything works save for when the input is:

```
get_slice(['r', 'i', 'g'], 0, 4)
```

Looking at the code, I can't understand why. The output if above input is given should be an empty list, and I created an elif to cover if the start value is lower then 1, then an empty list should be returned.

I'm hoping a fresh set of eyes will help me figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a set of if/elif/else statements, it will only evaluate the first one that is true.

In this case, the first one that is true is the first `if stop > length:` scenario. You can either make your conditions more complicated or make your check for the invalid scenarios the first one.